# SSRS Page Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm working on an SSRS report and have encountered an issue with the number of pages displayed when exporting to PDF. The report generates 15 pages in the report viewer, but when I export it to PDF, it shows more than 15 pages. I'm wondering if there is a way to resolve this issue and ensure that the PDF version matches the number of pages displayed in the report viewer.

in ssrs report generate the report and in report viewer it shows 15 page for that report and when i export to the pdf of that report it shows more than 15 pages how can i fix  this issue

Comment: does the report show page numbers somewhere? are the extra pages on PDF black or with valid data?

Comment: Do you have the same settings for PageSize and InteractiveSize?

Comment: Yes, same settings for PageSize and InteractiveSize

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have sufficient rights to post a comment, I am posting a reply.

I also work with paginated reports in MS Report Builder that should be output as PDF. In my experience, there are several causes that can lead to the number of pages in the PDF not being as expected, namely:

1. PageSize and InteractiveSize

As mentioned in the comments, care must be taken with PageSize and InteractiveSize to ensure that the values match.

2. Width of the body

The width of the body must be equal to the PageSize minus the left and right margins and minus a tolerance.

Example: My PDF reports are in DIN A4 format (portrait). I use millimeters (mm) as the unit of measurement.

The width of a DIN A4 sheet is 210 mm.
As margins left and right I defined 20 mm each.
Then I subtract a tolerance of 1 mm.

This results in the following width for the body: 210 - (20 x 2) - 1 = 169 mm.

I include the tolerance because I have noticed that unwanted page breaks can occur when objects (tablix, rectangles, lines, diagrams, text boxes, etc.) end exactly at the right page margin.

What can also happen is that the width of the body is unintentionally increased. This can happen relatively easily by moving objects or mistyping size specifications. Unfortunately, in MS Report Builder there is no possibility to define the size of the body as fixed. So you have to check this from time to time.

3. Height of the body

The body may be any height, but not higher than necessary. When the report is ready, simply enter a value for the height of the body that is clearly too low. MS Report Builder will automatically reduce the height to the required value. So no content will be cut off.

4. Tablix properties

Here the page break options have to be considered. The settings "Add page break before / after" and "Keep together on one page if possible" can also lead to unwanted page breaks.

[tablix_properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csi36.png)

Note here that if the tablix consists of one or more row groups, there are also similar properties for each of these groups.

[group_properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofi8d.png)

5. web / print layout

It makes a difference whether you look at the report in the web view or the print view when you run the report. The margins are added only when you switch to the print view. This can increase the number of pages in the report, see example:

[Web or Print View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtFde.png)

If this is the case, then this is correct. It makes a difference if the report is designed for web or for print.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Set all the properties that mention above but not get the solution of the problem

Comment: I edited my answer because I took a picture to illustrate and it cannot be used in the Comments, see point 5 in the answer.